# Use of Undeclared Identifier 'Length' and 'maxSize' from Base Class Template?

Tags: c++

I was completing an assignment for a lab in my C++ class, and I came across this problem where all of the `protected` variables from my base class haven't been declared for use in my derived class, and I'm not sure why. I've been trying to solve this for a while, and can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

template <class elemType>
class arrayListType {

    public:
        const arrayListType<elemType>& operator=(const arrayListType<elemType>&);

        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool isFull() const;
        int listSize() const;
        int maxListSize() const;
        void print() const;
        bool isItemAtEqual(int loc, int item) const;
        void removeAt(int loc);
        void retrieveAt(int loc, int& retItem);
        void clearlist();

        virtual int seqSearch(int searchItem) const = 0;
        virtual void insertAt(int loc, int insertItem) = 0;
        virtual void insertEnd(int insertItem) = 0;
        virtual void replaceAt(int loc, int repItem) = 0;
        virtual void remove(int removeItem) = 0;

        arrayListType(int size = 100);
        arrayListType(const arrayListType& otherList);

        virtual ~arrayListType();

    protected:
        int *list;
        elemType length;
        elemType maxSize; 


};

template <class elemType>
bool arrayListType<elemType>::isEmpty() const {
    return (length == 0);
}

template <class elemType>
bool arrayListType<elemType>::isFull() const {
    return (length == maxSize);
}

template <class elemType>
int arrayListType<elemType>::listSize() const {
    return length;
}

template <class elemType>
int arrayListType<elemType>::maxListSize() const {
    return maxSize;
}

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::print() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << list[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

template <class elemType>
bool arrayListType<elemType>::isItemAtEqual(int loc, int item) const {
    if (loc < 0 || loc >= length) {
        cout << "The item's location is out of range" << endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        return (list[loc] == item);
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::removeAt(int loc) {
    if (loc < 0 || loc >= length) {
        cout << "The item's location is out of range" << endl;
    } else {
        for (int i = loc; i < length - 1; i++) {
            list[i] = list[i + 1];
            length --;
        }
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::retrieveAt(int loc, int& retItem) {
    if (loc < 0 || loc >= length) {
        cout <<"The item's location is out of range" << endl;
    } else {
        retItem = list[loc];
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void arrayListType<elemType>::clearlist() {
    length = 0;
}

template <class elemType>
arrayListType<elemType>::arrayListType(int size) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        cout << "You need a positive value for size, the default size is 100" << endl;
        maxSize = 100;
    } else {
        maxSize = size;
        length = 0;
        list = new int[maxSize];
    }
}

template <class elemType>
arrayListType<elemType>::~arrayListType() {
    delete [] list;
}

template <class elemType>
const arrayListType<elemType>& arrayListType<elemType>::operator= (const arrayListType<elemType>& otherList) {
    if (this != otherList) {
        delete [] list;
        maxSize = otherList.maxSize;
        length = otherList.maxSize;
        list = new elemType[maxSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            list[i] = otherList.list[i];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class elemType>
arrayListType<elemType>::arrayListType(const arrayListType& otherList) {
    maxSize = otherList.maxSize;
    length = otherList.length;
    int j;

    list = new int[maxSize];

    for (int i = 0; j < length; j++) {
        list[i] = otherList.list[j];
    }
}

template <class elemType>
class unorderedArrayListType :public arrayListType<elemType> {
    public:
        void insertAt(int loc, int insertItem);
        void insertEnd(int insertItem);
        void replaceAt(int loc, int repItem);
        int seqSearch(int searchItem) const;
        void remove(int removeItem);

        unorderedArrayListType(int size = 100);
};

template <class elemType>
void unorderedArrayListType<elemType>::insertAt(int loc, int insertItem) {
    if (loc < 0 || loc >= maxSize) {
        cout << "The item's position is out of range" << endl;
    } else if (length >= maxSize) {
        cout << "Can't insert items into a full list" << endl;
    } else {
        for (int i = length; i > loc; i--) {
            list[i] = list [i - 1];
            list[loc] = insertItem;
            length++;
        }
    }
}
    
template <class elemType>
void unorderedArrayListType<elemType>::insertEnd(int insertItem) {
    if (length >= maxSize) {
        cout << "Can't insert item into a full list" << endl;
    } else {
        list[length] = insertItem;
        length++;
    }
}

template <class elemType>
int unorderedArrayListType<elemType>::seqSearch(int searchItem) const {
    int col;
    bool found = false;

    for (col = 0; col < length; col++) {
        if (list[col] == searchItem) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        return col;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void unorderedArrayListType<elemType>::remove(int removeItem) {

    int col;

    if (length == 0) {
        cout << "You can't delete from an empty list" << endl;
    } else {
        col = seqSearch(removeItem);

        if (col != -1) {
            removeAt(col);
        } else {
            cout << "The item that needs to be deleted isn't in the list" << endl;
        }
    }
}

template <class elemType>
void unorderedArrayListType<elemType>::replaceAt(int loc, int repItem) {
    if (loc < 0 || loc >= length) {
        cout << "The item's location is out of range" << endl;
    } else {
        list[loc] = repItem;
    }
}

template <class elemType>
unorderedArrayListType<elemType>::unorderedArrayListType(int size): arrayListType(size) {
}

int main() {

    unorderedArrayListType<int> list(25);
    unorderedArrayListType<float> floatList(25);

    int num;
    int removeNum;
    float k;
    float repK;

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> num;
        list.insertEnd(num);
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "The current list is: ";
    list.print();

    cout << "Enter a number to remove: ";
    cin >> removeNum;
    cout << endl;
    list.remove(removeNum);

    cout << "The updated list is: ";
    list.print();

    cout << "Enter 5 numbers: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> k;
        list.insertEnd(k);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Type arrayListType<elemType>::maxSize, arrayListType<elemType>::length, etc.

Comment: Where would I type that? In the public part of the derived class?

Comment: Try. You'll see.